# Parse Cache Policy Creating Duplicates

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-server

I am setting a query's cache policy to `cacheThenNetwork` but when I load it, it is creating duplicates in my array to which is being duplicates in my tableview.

How do I go about this? Am I missing something?

Here is my query:

```
var searchListArray = [Search]()

func fetchSearch(completion: @escaping ([Search]) -> Void){

        searchListArray.removeAll()

        let brands = PFQuery(className: "Brands")
        brands.cachePolicy = .cacheThenNetwork
        brands.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects : [PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // results contains players with lots of wins or only a few wins.

                for brands in objects! {

                    let brandName = brands["vendor"] as! String
                    let brandLogo = brands["brand_logo"] as! PFFile

                    let searchList = Search(brandName: brandName, brandLogo: brandLogo, brandObject: brands)

                    searchListArray.append(searchList)

                }
                    completion(searchListArray)



            } else {

                    completion([])

                }

        })

}
```

Here is my call to this query:

```
var brandListArray = [Search]()
    var filtered = [Search]()

    func loadData(){

        brandListArray.removeAll()
        filtered.removeAll()

        fetchSearch(completion: { data -> Void in

            let sortedBrands = data.sorted(by: {$0.brandName < $1.brandName})

            self.brandListArray.append(contentsOf:sortedBrands)
            self.filtered.append(contentsOf:sortedBrands)
            self.tableView?.reloadData()

        })

    }
```

Comment: Please share us your code. It's too difficult to help without seeing source code.

Comment: @DJ-Glock Sorry about that, check above.